# Make a dataframe column with names of variables in the for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I have an issue with my code. Below is the code snippet:

```
abc = [1, 2, 3, 4]
def = [5, 6, 7, 8]

for i in [abc, def]:
   df[str(i)] = i   #This is giving an issue
```

I want to make abc and def (list) a column in my dataframe with column name as abc and def (Same as in for loop.

Is it possible. Can anybody help please

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. So in this case, you have a dataframe column whose name is the list, `df['[1, 2, 3, 4]']` and you're trying to assign the values `1,2,3,4` to the rows in that column?

Comment: Actually the name of the list is my column name and the values in it are the values of the column. but when i do .... for i in [abc, def]: df[abc] = abc, it assigns the column name as the values of abc and def respectively. I need only the names of the list as my column names

Comment: I want to do this ... df['abc] = [1, 2, 3, 4] and df['def] = [5, 6, 7, 8]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage on the [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) function that acts like a dict to hold the local variables:

```
abc = [1, 2, 3, 4]
def1 = [5, 6, 7, 8]     # rename 'def' to 'def1' since 'def' is a Python keyword

df = pd.DataFrame()

for i in ['abc', 'def1']:
   df[i] = locals()[i]
```

Here, `locals()['abc']` will resolve to the variable name `abc` which holds `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.  Thus, effectively it is the same as running the following code for the first iteration of the for loop:

```
df['abc] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Result:

```
print(df)

   abc  def1
0    1     5
1    2     6
2    3     7
3    4     8
```

Comment: Thankyou so much @SeaBean, you are indeed a life saver

Answer (score 1):

You can't (easily) do that with your variable declaration. Maybe you can try:

```
cols = {'abc': [1, 2, 3, 4], 
        'def': [5, 6, 7, 8]}

out = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(cols)], axis="columns")
```

```
>>> out
  xyz  abc  def
0   A    1    5
1   B    2    6
2   C    3    7
3   D    4    8
```