# Include Variable as Index Column in For Loop

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, mql5

I'm trying to add a variable from a list into a dataframe that is being passed through an appended list: The goal is to be able to identify the quotes with their respective symbol pairs:

```
symbol = ['EURUSD','USDJPY','USDCHF','USDCAD']
timeframe = mt.TIMEFRAME_M1
date_from = datetime(2023,10,27,16,55)
date_to = datetime.now()

price = []

for i in symbol:
    data = mt.copy_rates_range(i,timeframe,date_from,date_to)
    price.append(data['close'])
    prices = pd.DataFrame(price)

prices
```

**THE CURRENT RESULTS ARE:**

```
           0          1          2          3
0    1.05644    1.05654    1.05644    1.05640
1  149.63200  149.60200  149.58400  149.60400
2    0.90209    0.90217    0.90219    0.90238
3    1.38740    1.38726    1.38732    1.38729
```

**THE DESIRED RESULTS ARE:**

```
     PAIR          0          1          2          3
0  EURUSD    1.05644    1.05654    1.05644    1.05640
1  USDJPY  149.63200  149.60200  149.58400  149.60400
2  USDCHF    0.90209    0.90217    0.90219    0.90238
3  USDCAD    1.38740    1.38726    1.38732    1.38729
```

I've tried concat and using "+"
Tried this too:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68010466/make-a-dataframe-column-with-names-of-variables-in-the-for-loop](https://stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just to start each appending with `symbol` like this:

```
for i in symbol:
    price.append(symbol[i])
    data = mt.copy_rates_range(i,timeframe,date_from,date_to)
    price.append(data['close'])
    ...
```